# HTML - Searchbar does not work in internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, search, uisearchbar

Can anyone help?

I created this search bar that works in google chrome , but not in Internet Explorer .

If I press "Enter " or click on the search button nothing happens in Internet Explorer.

I should be redirected to a page , as what happens in chrome.

Any suggestion? Thank You!

```
<html>
  <body>

 <datalist id="colors">
    <option value="Red">
    <option value="Blue ">
    <option value="Green">
    <option value="Black">
  </datalist>


<input type="hidden" id="color"  name="color" value="RED" required>
<input type="hidden" id="color2"  name="color2" value="BLUE" required>
<input type="hidden" id="color3"  name="color3" value="GREEN" required>
<input type="hidden" id="color4"  name="color4" value="BLACK" required>

<form>
  <input type="search" list="colors" class="searchbox" id="searchbox" placeholder="What Color?" name="color_repeat" required autocomplete="off"
   onsearch="check(this)">
  <input type="button" class="button" id="button" value="Search" onclick="check(document.getElementById('searchbox'))">  
</form>

<script>
function check(input) 

{
if (input.value.toUpperCase() != document.getElementById('color').value)
{
if (input.value.toUpperCase() != document.getElementById('color2').value)  
{
if (input.value.toUpperCase() != document.getElementById('color3').value) 
{ 
if (input.value.toUpperCase() != document.getElementById('color4').value) 
{       

} 
else 
{ 
window.top.location.href = 'http://www.color.com.br/BLACK’
}
} 
else 
{ 
window.top.location.href = 'http://www.color.com.br/GREEN’
}
} 
else 
{ 
window.top.location.href = 'http://www.color.com.br/BLUE’
}
} 
else 
{ 
window.top.location.href = 'http://www.color.com.br/BLUE’
}

}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<body>

<datalist id="colors">
    <option value="Red">
    <option value="Blue ">
    <option value="Green">
    <option value="Black">
</datalist>

<form>
  <input type="search" list="colors" id="searchbox" placeholder="What Color?" name="color_repeat" required autocomplete="off"
   onsearch="location.href = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+document.getElementById('searchbox').value;">
  <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="location.href = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+document.getElementById('searchbox').value;">  
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This works in both Internet Explorer 11 and Google Chrome by taking your value and redirecting you to the appropriate Google search. However, the problem you were encountering was that the `onsearch` event is [not supported](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsearch.asp) in Internet Explorer. This can be circumvented by using the `onclick` event of the button instead, which is [supported](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp). I hope this helps with your issue!